# StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler Processing error

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, rabbitmq, stomp

I have a Stomp Client React JS chat application which connects to Java Spring and RabbitMQ in the backend. It was working until recently when I started getting the following whenever I send message to another user in the Java backend:

```
StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Received ERROR {message=[Processing error], content-type=[text/plain], version=[1.0,1.1,1.2], content-length=[16]} session=34716891-3169-4d36-b91c-06a6bcab2ff1 text/plain payload=Processing error
```

And in the browser the following error:

```
<<< ERROR
message:Processing error
content-type:text/plain
version:1.0,1.1,1.2
content-length:16

Processing error
```

And the message goes into the database but other user never gets notified

Comment: I was able to resolve it, my rabbitmq was throwing 500 error, so I just restarted it. But am still trying to figure out why the error occured in the first place